# Can I get CellID or WiFi HotSpot MAC address on Windows Phone 7 And How

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation

Can I get

- CellID or
- WiFi HotSpot MAC address

on Windows Phone 7.x? I do not want geo location, I want cellId and hotspot mac address.

If I can, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you could not. It is impossible with API provided now.

Comment: I also didn't find such API.  And I'm quite interested in learning how to determine there isn't the API I want.  I just don't know how.  Thanks!

Comment: All available API are described in msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626516(v=VS.92).aspx. Navigate through namespaces that probably matches your needs and see if there are any appropriate classes/methods exists.